# Equivalent of ${@} in the dependency list for GNU-style makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In Sun make, I can create a rule resembling the following:

```
${OBJECTS} : ${@F:%.o=%.c}
     (...) ${<}
```

... where ${@} in the dependency list is the same as ${@} in the rule portion of the target.  That way, ${<} always evaluates to the right source file for the object being built.

This is somewhat like doing rules of the form:

```
%.o : %.c
     (...) ${<}
```

My question is: is there a way to do this with GNU make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
%.o : %.c
    (...) $<
```

Or if you want to restrict the rule to `${OBJECTS}`:

```
${OBJECTS} : %.o : %.c
    (...) $<
```

Comment: Beautiful.  That appears to be precisely what I needed, thank you.